# Gyro data from iOS to PC (windows surface)

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gyroscope

I want to make a kind of pointer for a specific windows application using the gyro in my iphone but I can't seem to find how to connect the iphone to the PC and send the data through an app. All I can find is that it should be possible over BLE. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

What I have so far is an app that reads gyro data from the phone but no connectivity nor way to receive this on the windows end.

Comment: What I've found so far is that the latest bluetooth (BLE) supports profiles similar to classic bluetooth. One of these is for human interaction devices (HID OVER GATT) which seems to be about mice and the like. Does anyone have any more info on whether the iphone can act as a HID with any code examples? That would be great!

Comment: Doing it over TCP instead. Would have preferred bluetooth but it seems like too much of a hassle.

https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket